# Copy and Paste formatted text using zclip plugin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zeroclipboard, zclip

I am using zclip plugin for copying text to clipboard. It works fine for plain text.

But when I try to copy some formatted text say for eg:

I am having div with html as

```
<div id="formattedDiv">
  <b>Copied Text </b>
</div>
```

and when I apply zclip on some button to copy formmattedDiv text as

```
$("a#copyCustombtn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
     return $("#formattedDiv").html()
    }
  });
```

It copies entire html as `"<b>Copied Text </b>"`.

When I try to paste, it pastes exactly `"<b>Copied Text </b>"`

but not formatted text as "**Copied Text** "

Can anybody guide me, why this happening?

Comment: Where did you paste it?

Comment: I tried to paste it, on editable div. But it paste the text as it is including all tags :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently zclip won't provide such a way to implement.
Raised an issue on **github** please refer [**to link**](https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip/issues/12) in which suggestion are welcomed.

Hope it will be implemented soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Zclip will only copy text to your clipboard. If you include HTML characters in that text, it will copy the html characters to your clipboard, not the formatted text.

If you only want the text and not the HTML characters, use:

```
copy: function () {
  return $("#formattedDiv").text()
}
```